# Node cannot find modules in IIS, can find from prompt

Tags: node.js, iis, module, npm, iisnode

I have installed some modules via `npm install <module>` and I can access them when I run `node` at the command prompt, but when I run the app under IIS using `iisnode`, I get errors like:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Cannot find module 'formidable'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\helloworld\hello.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

What is going on? Is there a different way I have to install modules if I am using `iisnode`?

Here is my `web.config` file from the project:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="hello.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: it should work. Please show more code & config.

Comment: OK, I added my `web.config` file. I'm not sure what else to add, everything else is the same as the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since npm 1.0, there are two ways to install things: Globally & Locally. Read documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html).

Global install (with `-g`) for something you want to use in your shell or on the command line.

When you install a package locally, via `npm install onepackage`, it will insert the dependency into package.json and add the library under the directory `node_modules`. This is mainly for a package you want to use in your program, using `require('onepackage')`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the problem. Unlike most package managers I've used, `npm` does not install things globally, but only to the folder you are located in when you install. I installed in the correct folder and it seems to be working.