# How to use node-oracle with iisnode?

Tags: node.js, oracle, iis, iisnode, node-oracledb

I'm having trouble trying to run a Node.js server with node-oracle via iisnode. The iisnode examples all work, and running the server [on a different port] in a Command Window works perfectly.  The server setup is based upon "The Node Beginner Book" example (i.e. index.njs -> server.njs -> router.njs -> requesthandlers.njs).  I renamed all of my node files as *.njs and currently have my web.config set up for iisnode to handle all files of that extension, with a rewrite rule to forward the incoming requests to index.njs.  The problem occurs when node-oracle -- utilized within requesthandlers.njs -- attempts to call oracle_bindings.node:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: The specified module could not be found.

c:\Program Files\iisnode\www\Reports\node_modules\oracle\build\Release\oracle_bindings.node
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\iisnode\www\Reports\node_modules\oracle\lib\oracle.njs:2:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I've given read/write/execute permissions to the IIS_IUSRS group on every folder imaginable within the .\iisnode\www\Reports\node_modules\oracle path.  I've also attempted the solution in [Node cannot find modules in IIS, can find from prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052573/node-cannot-find-modules-in-iis-can-find-from-prompt) to no avail.  While I could probably just set the server up as a service, I'd prefer to have it through IIS so that I don't have to battle with CORS while supporting IE9.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution

Comment: @MuhanadY - No, I succumbed to using it as a service.  You can use Corey Butler's, [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) for that.  At that time I wasn't using Express.js, but Express should handle any CORS concerns.

Comment: well, I finally made it work. I downloaded 0.2.21 ver. of issnode and set up the samples. after that ı was able to make my solution work. about finding the modules, by running the setup inside the folder all modules will installed.

Comment: @MuhanadY - Congrats!  Add it as an answer so it gets visibility.  I'm no longer working on that project and don't have access to the same servers, but once I can confirm I'll mark it as the accepted answer.